# Should back button exist in PWA (Progressive Web Applications)?

Tags: ios, chrome, pwa

What's the reason there's no back button for ios or android in pwa?

I can implement the button and the behavior by myself, but should I?

Why are the mobile apps not common to navigate backwards/forwards?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the application that you are designing. If

- there is only one page OR
- there is only a flat hierarchy (Inbox, Trash bin, Settings) OR
- users are unlikely to go back in a set of steps

then you probably don't need it.

Also, android provides a back button natively. For iOS you still have to add it. Maybe something like this?

[image: iOS interface with back button]